# SODA between operator does not work with some datasets

Tags: socrata, soda

The `between` operator works for some Socrata SODA datasets and not for others.  When used on certain datasets the query yields no results, but on other datasets it works as expected. What am I doing wrong?

Instead of using `between` I tried using `>=` which did yield results.  Also, I tried using `between` on a different dataset which worked as expected.

For example, using `between` on the `:updated_at` field in this query yields no results.

```sh
curl "https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/3h2n-5cm9.json?%24select=%3A*%2C*&%24where=%3Aupdated_at+between+%272019-01-10T10%3A00%3A00.000%27+and+%272019-09-11T10%3A00%3A00.000%27&%24limit=10"
[]
```

However, there is data because `:updated_at >=` yields results.

```sh
curl "https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/3h2n-5cm9.json?%24select=%3A*%2C*&%24where=%3Aupdated_at+%3E%3D+%272019-01-10T10%3A00%3A00.000%27&%24limit=10"
[{":created_at":"2019-09-11T22:23:43.719Z",":id":"row-qu6f_f9ar_rewb",":updated_at":"2019-09-11T22:23:43.719Z"
...]
```

Here's an example of `between` working for a different dataset.

```sh
curl "https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/rvhx-8trz.json?%24select=%3A*%2C*&%24where=%3Aupdated_at+between+%272019-01-10T10%3A00%3A00.000%27+and+%272019-09-11T10%3A00%3A00.000%27&%24limit=10"
[{":created_at":"2018-05-25T21:44:12.712Z",":id":"row-a34u.9rem~mnnx",":updated_at":"2019-01-10T22:23:58.425Z",":version":"rv-xahg~4nmg.r4c2"
...]
```

The `between` operator used to work on the `https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/3h2n-5cm9.json` dataset but does not as of 11 Sep 2019 10 pm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspecting the following query returns results, but none of the results appear to be prior to `2019-09-11T10:00:00`

```
https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/3h2n-5cm9.json?$select=:*,*&$where=:updated_at >= '2019-01-10T10:00:00'
```

Since a couple days have passed, the following query does appear to return all results (I've adjusted the latter date to the current date, September 13th, 2019:

```
https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/3h2n-5cm9.json?$select=:*,*&$where=:updated_at between '2019-01-10T10:00:00' AND '2019-09-13T10:00:00'
```

When looking at this file, I noticed all of the `:updated_at` timestamps are the same (`2019-09-11T22:23:43.719Z` at the moment). [The info box in this section](https://dev.socrata.com/docs/system-fields.html#version-21) helps explain the field a bit. My guess is NYC is doing a complete replace so the `:updated_at` is completely changed each day because all records are rewritten.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I should have done a `min` on `:updated_at`.  Apologies for the noise.

Comment: No problem! It threw me for a bit as well.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is not directly an answer but have you tried submitting this question to https://support.socrata.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?

Good luck.

Jon

Comment: Thanks Jon. I wasn't aware of that.